# Accessing pandas multi-index with a variable

Tags: python, pandas

I'm struggling to access a Pandas DataFrame with a multi-index programatically. Let's say I have

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[0, 0, 0, 1],
                  [0, 0, 1, 2], 
                  [0, 1, 0, 7],
                  [0, 1, 1, 9],
                  [1, 0, 0, 1],
                  [1, 0, 1, 0],
                  [1, 1, 0, 1],
                  [1, 1, 1, 10]], columns=['c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'value'])

sums = df.groupby(['c1', 'c2', 'c3']).value.sum()
```

I can get the sum which corresponds to the [1, 1, 1] combination of c1, c2 and c3 with

```
sums[1, 1, 1]
```

That returns 10 as expected.

But what if I have a variable

```
q = [1, 1, 1]
```

how do I get the same value out?

I have tried

```
sums[q]
```

which gives

```
c1  c2  c3
0   0   1     2
        1     2
        1     2
Name: value, dtype: int64
```

Also I thought star operator could work:

```
sums[*q]
```

but that is invalid syntax.

Comment: use eval and a string representation

Comment: @KannappanSirchabesan that's not a good suggestion

Comment: @RafaelC  any specific reason?

Comment: It's a horrible design to store indexes in a string and then `eval` the string for infinite reasons.. For example, you have just *hardcoded* the operation you want to make, and you'd have to perform string operations if you had to manipulate any of the indexes (which is slow and unnecessarily costly).

Comment: @RafaelC Thanks for the explanation. what would be your acceptable answer for this question? or is the question in itself lends to an inefficient answer?

Comment: @KannappanSirchabesan jezrael presented nice ways to solve this problem ;}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.xs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.xs.html) with `tuple`:

```
print (sums.xs((1,1,1)))
10
```

Or [`Series.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.loc.html):

```
print (sums.loc[(1,1,1)])
#alternative
#print (sums[(1,1,1)])
10
```

---

```
q = [1, 1, 1]
print (sums.loc[tuple(q)])
#alternative
#print (sums[tuple(q)])
10
```

Comment: I looked at the code for `__getitem__`  and saw the tuple behaviour now. If you change your answer to `sums[tuple(q)]` I'll accept it.